# JAVAX PRINT Creating blank page when i set print job from java

Tags: java, pdf, printing, javax

I had set Microsoft Print to PDF as default and executed below code, it creates PDF file with 0KB. Had set Microsoft Print to PDF to test if print option works or not.

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\pdfs\\MI1.pdf"));
          DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
          PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
          DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
          Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
          PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
          printJob.print(doc, attributes);
          is.close();
```

Comment: solved it after 4 to 5 hours of R&D

Answer (score 0):

solved it after 4 to 5 hours of R&D--------------------------------------------

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.print.PrintService;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class PrintController {

    // Printing service
    @SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "null" })
    public static void mainPrinting(String[] args) throws PrinterException {
        // Set required printer name
        String printerNameDesired = "HPE647CF (HP Officejet Pro 6830)";
        // Get all printer services
        PrintService[] service = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices(); // list of
        int count = service.length;
        PrintService printer = null;
        // loop to get required printer serices
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (service[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired)) {
                System.out.println("=====>" + service[i].getName());
                printer = service[i];
            }
        }
        // if printer service is not empty then print
        if (!printer.getName().isEmpty()) {
            List<String> supplierNames = Arrays.asList("MI1.pdf");
            for (String supplierName : supplierNames) {

                File file = new File("D:\\pdfs\\" + supplierName);
                // create the docuemnt with file on local machine
                PDDocument document = null;
                try {
                    document = PDDocument.load(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // create the job
                PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                // set unique name to each file
                job.setJobName(supplierName);
                job.setPrintService(printer);
                job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
                try {
                    job.print();
                } catch (PrinterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```